# Ways to input into different databases

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for the best way to input data into different databases. Right now I've got a page with a drop down menu that asks what database they want to enter into, then that page takes you to a form page that has where you can type information. The problem I'm having is that the if statement is not working correctly.

```
<form action="test.php" method="GET"> 
<select name="dropdown"> 
<option value="a">Database1</option> 
<option value="b">Database2</option>  
<input type="submit">
</select> 
</form> 


 <?php
   if(isset($_GET['dropdown']) && $_GET['dropdown'] === 'a'){
      include 'test.php';
    }  else if($_GET['dropdown'] === 'b'){
       include 'Test2.php';
   }
 ?>
```

Regardless of whether I click `Database1` or `Database2` I still land on the first test page. Now, I'm assuming this is because the action of the drop down is the first `test.php` page, but I'm not sure what I need to change that to in order to incorporate all 3 options.

I feel like even if I get this to work, there has got to be a more efficient way to do this. Maybe a single page where I can have the user choose from the drop down menu, and then whatever data he enters will be sent to the correct data base.

Comment: `if($_POST['dropdown'] === "a"){...}` etc.

Comment: @EdCottrell Seems like it :) why did you delete yours? It was better and should have been an answer.

Comment: The reason why your code is failing is that you're not checking to see if anything is set or is equal to the value passed, nor are you assigning a GET variable. I also made a typo in my comment, which should have read as `if($_GET['dropdown'] === "a")`

Comment: You've edited your question using posted code from answers given, which should have been marked as an **Edit** under your original post.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, ya i noticed that right after I hit submit. I went back to add notes as to why I edited it, but they haven't shown up.

Comment: If your entire code is inside the same page, use `action=""` instead of `action="test.php"` which is what I did to test and using what I posted in my answer below. See the additional notes in it also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- WOW, it looks like that fixed it! Hopefully I won't have anymore dumb questions today. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're very much welcome, glad to have helped. Cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- Meh, your answer's good, and you deserved this one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have edited your question and your original code is not showing.

As per your [**original post**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24961494/1)

The reason why your code is failing is that you're not checking to see if anything is set or is equal to the value passed, nor are you assigning any GET variables.

You also need an `else` if your 3rd option is chosen or use a 3rd conditional i.e.: `if($_GET['dropdown'] === 'c'){...}`

```
if(isset($_GET['dropdown']) && $_GET['dropdown'] === 'a') {
  include 'test.php';

// echo "A chosen";

} else if($_GET['dropdown'] === 'b'){
  include 'Test2.php';

// echo "B other";

}

else if($_GET['dropdown'] === 'c'){...}
    echo "Other, C chosen";
}
```

Sidenote: I noticed that you are using mixed case for your files.

`test.php` and `Test2.php` - on Linux systems, `test2.php` and `Test2.php` are not the same thing should this be a contributing factor to possible errors you may be getting.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

---

If your entire code is inside the same page, use `action=""` instead of `action="test.php"` which is what I did to test my code here, which I suspect may be the issue or a contributing one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want ..

```
if(isset($_GET['dropdown']) && $_GET['dropdown'] === 'a') {
// the rest of ur code
}
```

Comment: *"I think this is what you want"* - It's indeed a good answer, yet I like to think that an added explanation as to why OP's code is failing would be beneficial ;-)

Comment: (addendum) Had you done that, you'd of most likely have been upvoted. It's all about learning ;-) Plus, OP is using a GET method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for mentioning ..i havnt noticed it ..:D

Comment: still having the same issue. I'm obviously missing something simple here since everyone whose commented has given almost the same answer lol

Comment: I updated my original post with the suggestions given, still having same issue as before. Feelin like a dummy right now lol.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, yes use new version of PHP and MYSQLi function to insert input in different databases

```
$db=new mysqli('localhost','root','');
if($db->connect_errno > 0 )
{
    die("Unable to connect data base");
}

if(isset($_GET["dropdown"]) && $_GET["dropdown"]=="a") 
{
$sql="insert into database1.tblTest(name) values('".$_GET["txtName"]."')";
} else if(isset($_GET["dropdown"]) && $_GET["dropdown"]=="b"){
$sql="insert into database2.tblTest(name) values('".$_GET["txtName"]."')";
}

if(!$result=$db->query($sql))
{
die("there was an error: ".$db->error);
}
else
{
echo "Saved...";
}
```

to use new version my PHP and MYSQLi function there is two pros
1. you can insert input in your select database
2. And MYSQLi function is Improved function of Mysql it protects from SQL Injection

thank you...

Comment: MySQLi doesn't automatically protect against MySQL injections.